# $location.path not loading a html file on button click using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js

I have an html my.html which contains a button on whose click I want to send user to about.html, now the problem I am facing is on button click I am going inside controller but when I call method

```
$location.path("\about")
```

Nothing happens only my current page appears, but my about.html doesn't loads.

I tried using `$window.open('/about.html', '_self');` and it is working perfectly fine but I don't know why `$location.path` is not working for me.

Also I am using `<base href="http://localhost:8080/" />`. Is it causing any problem ??

**my.html** code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="http://localhost:8080/" />
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-route.js"></script>

    <!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular-

cookies.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="js/controller.js"></script>
    <div class="container">
      <div ng-controller="loginCtrl">
        <form id="myLogin">
          <div class="row" style="margin-top: 100px;text-align: center;">
            <div  class="col-sm-12" align="center">
              <h2>Log In</h2>
              <table >
                <tr>
                  <td>User Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter user name" 

                                                id="username" ng-model="username"></td>
                </tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr>
                <tr>
                  <td> Password:</td><br><td> <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter 

                    Password" id="password" ng-model="password"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td><button type="button" ng-click="submit()">Log In</button></td></tr>
              </table>

            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**controller.js**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
  console.log("hello");
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $routeProvider
  .when('/about',{
    templateUrl:  'about.html'
  })
  .otherwise({
    templateUrl:  'about.html'

  });
});


app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $location){
  console.log("hello1")
  $scope.submit=function(){
    var uname=$scope.username;
    var pwd=$scope.password;
    console.log("inside controller");

    $location.path('/about');
  };
});
```

Can anyone of you please tell me how can i do this in AngularJS.

**about.js**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <p>yes</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```js
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}))

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log("Global");
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/my.html');
});
var util = require('util');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
http.createServer(app).listen(8080);
```

My **directory structure** is defined below and i am running nodejs server with app.js

```
project/
         my.html
         about.html
         app.js
         js/
           controller.js 
           angular.js
           angular-route.js
```

Comment: Any errors in the `console`? Have you tried to remove the `base` tag?

Comment: no error i am able to go to the controller from button click correctly, when i am cicking on button then my url is changing to http://localhost:8080/about but my about.html does get loaded.

Comment: yes i have tried to remove base tag still now working for me.

Comment: Could it be that $location is "undefined" ? Try to inject the $location service to your controller:
app.controller('loginCtrl',["$scop","$location", function($scope, $location){
...
}])
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Comment: no location is not undefined as when i am trying to print location it is printing object with $$absUrl as "http://localhost:8080/about"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `ng-view`.

> The $route service is typically used in conjunction with the ngView directive and the $routeParams service.

<sup>https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route</sup>

All the views will render into this node so you should move the login view into a different `.html` file (`home.html` in my example).

Working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/TvPU7f6YFEnFIom5JQRu?p=preview

Comment: then how can i inject main layout (index.html) into different html pages.

Comment: You don't. See the files list in the plunkr (I updated the link). The index.html will hold the layout only, the other `html`s files will contains only partial views (e.g. without `html`, `body` etc. tags).

Comment: just tell me one more thing where are you specifying login page(my.html) ??

Comment: in `home.html`. Can't you see it in the plunkr?

Comment: sorry my bad last problem i am getting error  $animate.enter(...).done is not a function ??

Comment: `i am getting error $animate.enter(...).done` - Where? I can't find this code in the question. Maybe you are using some plugin which should add transition between views? Which plugin? Can you create a plunkr with this problem?

Comment: https://github.com/sudhanshugaur4/angular . Here m.js is my controller.js remember and app.js is my node server file.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this syntax but maybe check if you missing some file of plugin or version issues.

Comment: my prblem is solved now just leave it and thanks a lot man (y)

Answer (score 0):

[$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/%24location) does not cause a full page reload when the browser URL is changed. To reload the page after changing the URL, use the lower-level API, $window.location.href.

```
$window.location.href = '/views/Dummy.html';
```

Comment: as i stated in my post i have used window.open and also window methods are working perfectly fine for me but i don't know why $location.path is not giving me desired result. Thanks anyways.

Comment: $timeout(function () {
   $location.path('/about'); 
}, 0);

Answer (score 0):

> Nothing happens only my current page appears, but my about.html
>   doesn't loads.

Hi! I'm new here! But maybe I can help you :)

Be carefull that `$location.path` doesn't reload your page, if that path of destination is the same of your current path. I'm suggesting you to use [$route](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route) as `$route.reload()` for reload a page with the same path.

Comment: but i have seen in every tutorial that simple $location.path() works fine for them, thye don;t use any other thing.